# Unfulfilled EXPECT_CALL in gtest when passing vector by setargreferee

Tags: c++, vector, googletest, googlemock

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

enum class InfoState : uint8_t
{
    OFF     = 0,
    ON      = 1,

};

class MyInfo
{
public:
    MyInfo(){};
    MyInfo(const MyInfo&){};
    MyInfo& operator=(const MyInfo&){}
    MOCK_METHOD0(getState, InfoState(void));
};

class ServiceClient
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(getInfo, bool(std::vector<MyInfo> &myInfoList));
};

class MyClassA
{
public:
    ServiceClient m_serviceClient;

    void updateStatus()
    {
        std::vector<MyInfo> myInfoList;
        if (m_serviceClient.getInfo(myInfoList))
        {
            for (auto& info: myInfoList)
            {
                if (InfoState::ON == info.getState())
                {
                    //notifyObservers(true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

TEST(infoTest, test1)
{
    MyClassA testObj;

    std::vector<MyInfo> myTestInfoList(1);

    EXPECT_CALL(myTestInfoList[0], getState()).WillOnce(::testing::Return(InfoState::ON));

    EXPECT_CALL(testObj.m_serviceClient, getInfo(::testing::_))
         .WillOnce(::testing::DoAll(::testing::SetArgReferee<0(myTestInfoList),::testing::Return(true)));

    testObj.updateStatus();
}
```

I want to test MyClassA::updateStatus method. In this case I want to set on MyInfo object inside myTestInfoList EXPECT_CALL with return value InfoState::ON.
Then I put my list to tested method by SetArgReferee. When it comes to execution of info.getState() it returns InfoState::OFF and gtest says "Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.".
Why this problem occurs and how I can test it ?

Comment: `EXPECT_CALL`s are doing copies internally - seems to me that `myTestInfoList` gets copied internally, so the expect calls you set are set on different object than used inside the `updateStatus` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Quarra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076113/quarra) comment, the main problem is a copy constructor. I am not a `Google Test` specialist, yet I found a solution to your problem.

As per `GMock`, I found out that mocked objects cannot be copied - this is the design principle and the decision of `Google Test` implementers. [Here this decision has been justified](https://groups.google.com/g/googlemock/c/GD73UXjQowE?pli=1) back in 2009.

Therefore by not defining the copy constructor inside of mocked objects, it will be deleted ([live code](https://godbolt.org/z/3qW4x8)). Here is the error code

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/googletest/release-1.10.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:1483:3: note: 'FunctionMocker' has been explicitly marked deleted here

  FunctionMocker(const FunctionMocker&) = delete;
```

Yet the main problem here is in fact the actual need of a copy constructor, and this is caused by two factors:

1. As I stated before GMock by design deletes copy construction, and even if you will create your own implementation - all `EXPECT_CALL` and other GMock essential functionalities would not be copied! This is exactly the issue you are having. So you've created a custom copy constructor, and all GMock functionality is gone. Despite the fact that this constructor is empty - it will not work out of the box anyway.

```
MyInfo(const MyInfo&){};
```

2. Second problem is the `std::vector` which you are using demands from you (in this use-case) that the type meets the [CopyConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible) concept. Therefore this will not work.

What concerns me is the fact that `EXPECT_CALL` is using copy instead of move semantics or passing a reference. This is done despite the fact that you explicitly set that argument shall be a reference (not a copy!) `SetArgReferee<0>(myTestInfoList)`. Moreover by design `GMock` objects are not copyable. This looks like a design flaw or bug to me, yet I am not a `Google Test` expert. I will do more research on that and maybe raise a bug report/question to `GTest` implementors.

Ok but to find the solution we need to first find a method in `GMock API` which do not use a copy, and afterward use `std::vector` functionality which is not calling a copy constructor.

The first problem will be solved by changing `EXPECT_CALL` to `ON_CALL` and to open the possibility for calling `std::vector` functionality we will also use `Invoke` from `GMock` API.
([Live code](https://godbolt.org/z/bG58xK))

```
TEST(infoTest, test1)
{
    MyClassA testObj;

    std::vector<MyInfo> myTestInfoList(1);

    ON_CALL(myTestInfoList[0], getState()).WillByDefault(::testing::Invoke(
            []()
            {
                return InfoState::ON;
            }));

    ON_CALL(testObj.m_serviceClient, getInfo(::testing::_))
         .WillByDefault(::testing::Invoke(
            [](std::vector<MyInfo> &myInfoList)
            {
                return true;
            }));

    testObj.updateStatus();
}
```

This works with explicitly deleted `copy constructor` -> `MyInfo(const MyInfo&) = delete;` yet logic is also deleted right now.

To overcome the second problem, which is `STL` copy, we can simply use `std::swap` and fill passed `std::vector&`. Swapping values doesn't copy the data - hence we are good to go.

```
    ON_CALL(testObj.m_serviceClient, getInfo(::testing::_))
         .WillByDefault(::testing::Invoke(
            [&myTestInfoList](std::vector<MyInfo> &myInfoList)
            {
                std::swap(myInfoList, myTestInfoList);
                return true;
            }));
```

here is the working [solution](https://godbolt.org/z/P7Ybof).

As said before I will try to investigate why GMock `EXPECT_CALL` forces a copy.